# How to hide rows that contain one number out of a large list of part numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I am looking to be able to hide rows in a large spreadsheet where each row that gets hidden contains one of the part numbers in a large list of part numbers. The list of part numbers will be added to daily and will contain hundreds of part numbers.
The real world application is that I have a build list which has part numbers that need to be built but my shop only has to build certain ones so I would like to remove the ones that I do not have to build. Although our company is constantly coming up with new part numbers so the list keeps getting bigger and the items that we have to build changes on each project.

Comment: Please see [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Sorry please be more specific in what you need. do you have two sheets, one is a list of parts and one is a list of parts you want to disregard in the first sheet ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you are getting the list of parts to check but the loop to hide any row which isn't in a given parts list could be done like below:

```
    Sub HideRows(ByVal PartNumArray As Variant, ByVal ColumnToSearch As String)

Dim LastRowData As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim HideRow As Boolean

LastRowData = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Rows(1 & ":" & LastRowData).EntireRow.Hidden = False 'Unhide All the rows (optional)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Use this to speed up the processing
For i = LastRowData To 1 Step -1
    HideRow = True
    For j = LBound(PartNumArray) To UBound(PartNumArray)
        If ActiveSheet.Range(ColumnToSearch & i).Text = PartNumArray(j) Then
        'Alternatives for boolean condition
            'ActiveSheet.Range(ColumnToSearch & i).Text like "*" & PartNumArray(j) & "*" 'For similar matches
            'Instr(1, ActiveSheet.Range(ColumnToSearch & i).value, PartNumArray(j)) > 0 'See if the part number is anywhere in the string
            HideRow = False

        End If
        If HideRow Then
            Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next 'Part to look for
Next 'Row
Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'Turn this back on so you can click on the screen again

End Sub
```

The trick is initializing the PartNumArray with the list of parts you want. I've included two different methods here:

```
'Sample of how to call the hide function
Sub TestSample()
    Dim PartNumArray As Variant

    PartNumArray = Array("42", "45A2", "573A-5")

    Call HideRows(PartNumArray, "A")
End Sub

'Sample of how to fill an array from a worksheet
Sub Fill_Array_With_Part_Numbers()
Dim LastRowData As Long, i As Long
Dim PartNumArray() As String
Dim ColumnToSearch As String
ColumnToSearch = "A"

LastRowData = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To LastRowData
    ReDim Preserve PartNumArray(0 To (i - 1))
    PartNumArray(i - 1) = ActiveSheet.Range(ColumnToSearch & i).Value
Next

For i = LBound(PartNumArray) To UBound(PartNumArray)
    Debug.Print "Array Index : " & i & " value is : " & PartNumArray(i)
Next i

End Sub
```